# Regex: 9 integers but spaces and minus characters allowed

Tags: .net, regex

I need a regex that as a minimum has 9 numbers and a maximum of 9 numbers. but these numbers can be split up with spaces or minus characters
Here are some sample strings with true or false to show what i want:

```
11-222-3333 true
11 222 3333 true
112223333   true
112-23-4567 true
11223333    false
11 22333333 false
1122333333  false
```

I currently use this regex: `^[0-9\s\-]{9,11}$`  but it allows for more then 9 numbers if there are no spaces or minuses in the string.

I want a minimum of 9 numbers and maximum of 9 numbers. So i need to ignore the spaces and minuses in the counting of the characters but I can't find how. Does someone know a correct way to do this?

Comment: Have it to be one regex? a simple str-replace before would be easier in this case...

Comment: javascript? java? .net?

Comment: Simple way: remove all that is not a digit and check the string length.

Comment: it's for a .net model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this lookahead based regex:

```
\b(?=(?:[ -]?\d){9}\b)[\d -]+\d\b
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/yQ6jC6/1)

`(?=(?:[ -]?\d){9}\b)` is positive lookahead assertion to ensure there are 9 digits with an optional space or hyphen before each digit.

Comment: I see, are these numbers appearing separately on each line?

Comment: they both work, gonna look at this positive lookahead assertion thing since i don't know it's meaning, thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following (without lookaheads):

```
^(\d[- ]*){9}$
```

**Logic**: Each digit can be optionally followed by either `-` or `space`.. and the number of digits should be 9

See [RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/jR6dC2/1)

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte no it will work the same because we are interested in numbers only. Unexpected results are only possible if one of `-` or `space` is a part of a `word`... If I am wrong can you think of a failing case? I will be happy to improve my answer :)

Comment: This one allows 10 digits http://fiddle.re/01n686, thank you for it cause it still works better then mine

Comment: @SjoerdDeWit updated according to your use case.. please check the updated regex :)